# Dividing by 10 not sure about formula

Tags: arithmetic

I have 2139 and I want to divide it into 10 people where 1 should get 3 times more than the 9 other. Solutions below:

`Solution A:`

> What I did is get 30% of the total and give it to the that person and divide the rest to 9 equally solution is

```
2139 * 30% = 641.70
2139 - 641.70 = 1494.3
1494.3 / 9 = 166.03

Person who gets 3 times more will get 641.70
Other 9 will get 166.03
```

`Solution B:`
What I did is divide the total by 12 then multiply the result by 3 that will be the amount to the person who will get 3 times more.

```
2139 / 12 = 178.25
178.25 * 3 = 534.75


Person who gets 3 times more will get 534.75
Other 9 will get 178.25
```

I am wondering which is the correct solution. I am confused why get the different outcome for Solution A and Solution B

Comment: `which is the correct solution` Just check in which case one person actually got $3$ times more than the others.

Comment: @dxiv I believe he wants to learn WHY the incorrect one is incorrect one, though. Good idea for checking the solution, though.

Comment: @NL628 Quite possibly so, and your answer covers that part nicely (+1). However, the OP should *state* that into the question, and also realize that once they identified the right answer it's a lot easier to figure out where the fault lies with the wrong answer.

Comment: True, you know better than me :D As I am new to this SE XD

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you think *either* would be correct.

Comment: This question has nothing whatsoever to do with division algebras. Why do people select tags randomly? In particular when the tag has a wiki explaining its meaning???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution A is incorrect because the one with the most does NOT get $30\%$ of the total. In fact, assume that that person gets $3x$ things and the other $9$ people each get $x$ things. Then, the total is $3x + 9x = 12x$. Thus, $\frac{3x}{12x}$ is the percentage that the first guy gets, which is actually $25\%$ not $30\%$

Thus, the Solution A is incorrect and the Solution B is correct.

Comment: I see that helps a lot I need time to tick the correct answer :)

Comment: @Guradio Thanks! I once was in middle school too :D Now I'm a high schooler, and I've done so many math competitions that I can help whenever you need! Good question :D